# The number of communities listed on the Tour page is not the same as on the About Us page

Tags: bug, tour

The [Tour](https://stackexchange.com/tour) page states that (bolding added for emphasis):

> Stack Exchange is a network of **177** communities that are created and run by experts and enthusiasts like you who are passionate about a specific topic.

The [About Us](https://stackexchange.com/about) page, however, states that

> Launched in 2010, the Stack Exchange network comprises **173** Q&A communities including Stack Overflow, the largest, most trusted online community for developers to learn, share their knowledge, and build their careers.

At least one of these numbers must be wrong.
Can we fix this discrepancy, please?

Comment: The top bar mouseover says 178...

Comment: The SE about page is static text that doesn't attempt to pull in actual numbers. It hasn't been updated there since at least early 2019. Weirdly, the stats on that page were updated to pull in data automatically, but that number did not receive the same treatment.

Comment: @animuson and the best part is that someone once said that Area51 isn't included in the count for some odd reason, to add to the confusion. Yet I bet we both know someone that just **loves** to use that number in trivia question and giggle every time someone gets the number wrong and has to wait a minute :P

Comment: There is also a couple of restricted access sites and an untold number of teams, do you want them included; better for any *statistic* to say "over" since there are also private websites which have purchased (leased) the code for their own use (adding a few more to the number).